# Sorting dynamic table content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, content, sort

I've been trying to use numerous jQuery plugins for tabling sorting in WordPress and have had absolutely no luck. Can anyone make a suggestion for a plugin that sorts tables of dynamic content?

I'm using the following code to generate the table:

```
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'cat'      => 1,
 'posts_per_page' => 10,
 'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$c = 0;
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>`

<table id="actArchive" class="tablesorter activity-archives" summary="This is the activities archive table">
<thead> 
  <tr>
   <th>Activity</th>
   <th>Episode</th>
   <th>Learning Goal</th>
   <th>Description</th>
 </tr>
</thead> 
<?php
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$epititle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pbsparents_rept', true);
$learninggoal = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pbsparents_replg', true);
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pbsparents_actshortdesc', true); ?>
  <tbody> 
    <tr class="<?=($c++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>">
       <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
       <td><?php echo $epititle; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $learninggoal; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<?php }
wp_reset_query();
```

Currently I'm attempting to use tablesorter.js to sort things and I've got everything working but when I click on the headings I want to sort, nothing happens.

On edit: Posting jQuery

```
$js162(function(){
  $js162("table").tablesorter({
     headers: {
     0: { sorter: "text" },
     1: { sorter: "digit" },
     2: { sorter: false },
     3: { sorter: false }
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: If you are successfully pulling data out of the WordPress tables, then this question isn't a **WordPress** question, but rather a **jQuery** question.

Comment: okay, thanks! I didn't know if maybe I was doing something wrong on the WP end.

Comment: Well, absent the jQUery, are you getting tabular data as you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, I am and I did some research that intimated that it may have something to do with the dynamic data. That's why I asked here first.

Comment: There may be other ways, but I can foresee two ways in which this issue might be WordPress-related: **1)** the querying of the data itself, and **2)** WordPress's use of *no-conflict mode* for jQuery. If you're getting your tabular data, I'm pretty sure you don't have a problem with querying the data (dynamic or otherwise), since at this point, you're looking at plain-old rendered, tabular, HTML content. So, I'd next look at whether your jQuery scripts use no-conflict mode.

Comment: To add to Chip's comment, can you post up the JS you're using to fire tablesorter?

Comment: Added the jquery as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try calling the table by ID instead of the generic 'table'.  Also, wrap your JS in a noconflict wrapper like this:

```
(function($) {
    $js162(function(){
      $js162("#actArchive").tablesorter({
         headers: {
         0: { sorter: "text" },
         1: { sorter: "digit" },
         2: { sorter: false },
         3: { sorter: false }
        }
     });
    });
})(jQuery);
```